# Hadoop - Connect to JobTracker

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and I trying to understand if it is possible to connect to either remote or local jobtracker, I need this because I want identify the task that Hadoop is currently executing, I am trying this sample I found:

```
public class MyTracker {

    MyTracker(){
        try{
            inetAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 50030);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    InetSocketAddress inetAddress = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyTracker myTracker = new MyTracker();
        myTracker.createJobTracker();
    }

    public void createJobTracker(){

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        try {
            JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(inetAddress, conf);
            JobStatus[] activeJobs = jobClient.jobsToComplete();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < activeJobs.length; i++){
                System.out.println(activeJobs[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50030 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:775)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:743)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
```

Please, help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: Which part of your code is Line 775 of the file "Client.java"? Thanks!

Comment: You have a version mismatch between your cluster and your local application.

Comment: Hi Alvin,Client.java a Hadoop API, I am not working there

Comment: Hi Thomas, you are right, I changed the hadoop.jar and it goes through that step, I am getting a different error now, but I believe it is better to open another thread for that.

Comment: actually, the error is not really resolved, when I changed the hadoop.jar I started getting error regarding missing classes, after fixing those error I am back to original error, any other idea on how to fix?

Comment: I am saying that I have the same version because I am using hadoop that is shipped with infosphere biginsight and I am using its jar to compile my code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run it and it indeed had a version missmatch plus this

[Jobtracker API error - Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50030 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813365/jobtracker-api-error-call-to-localhost-127-0-0-150030-failed-on-local-excepti?rq=1)

because I was trying to connect to port 50030 when I should connect to port 9001 as described in that thread.

thanks